# Generate equidistant sequence of number in one cell using Vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

Example:

```
A    B    C         D
Min Max Steps   Result
10  70   4      10,30,50,70
30  150  5      30,60,150,90,120   
40  100  2      40,100    
50  150  3      50,100,150   
60  160  6      60,80,140,100,120,160 
120 160  3      120,140,160
```

I Want to generate Result in D2 which are "equidistant sequence of number" (such as "10,30,50,70")  based on Min in A2, Max in B2 and Steps (unit count in that sequence) in C2. Then for the whole column D

My current method is calculate value of each unit in other sheet and merge them into Column D using Concatenate() Function

Can I improve it with vba?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please provide some more rule of function you need. One example can be not enough here

Comment: @KazimierzJawor I updated the examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function will do

```
Function EquidistanceSequence(min As Long, max As Long, steps As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = min To max Step steps
        EquidistanceSequence = EquidistanceSequence & i & ","
    Next i
    EquidistanceSequence = Left(EquidistanceSequence, Len(EquidistanceSequence) - 1)
End Function
```

to be used by a main sub like:

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("MyDataSheet") '<-- change "MyDataSheet" to your actual sheet name from which read input data from
        MsgBox EquidistanceSequence(.Range("A2").Value, .Range("B2").Value, .Range("C2").Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

or:

```
Sub main()
    MsgBox EquidistanceSequence(10, 70, 20)
End Sub
```

or directly in your excel UI, typing in any cell:

```
=EquidistanceSequence(A2;B2;C2)
```