# Formula for generating delimited list of incremented numbers

Tags: excel

Looking for a formula that takes a min and max value, then generates a delimited list of numbers including and between those values.

For example:

min = `2015`

max = `2017`

result = `2015,2016,2017`

Not sure what to call it/how to word it, everything I've tried gives me results unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,SEQUENCE(1,3,2015,1))
```

Comment: Any chance I can do it without `TEXTJOIN`? It Isn't available in my version of Excel :(

Comment: @Casey what is your `Excel` Version?

Comment: Office Professional Plus 2016

Comment: Alright, one moment!

Comment: Another caveat is the sequence may not always be 3 steps, it can be 1-many.

Comment: Aha okay, you need VBA then,!

Comment: @Casey are you using any cell references ?

Comment: I got yours working in Google sheets with the caveat by doing `=TEXTJOIN(",",,SEQUENCE(1,MINUS(max,min)+1,min,1))`

Comment: @Casey so is it resolved now then?

Comment: Yes, the `max` and `min` above are cell references. Now to find the VBA code to make my own `TEXTJOIN` and `SEQUENCE` for Excel! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Casey you can refer this link on `TEXTJOIN` using VBA -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165179/ms-excel-concat-with-a-delimiter/42165195#42165195

Comment: @Casey refer the answer by Scott Craner!

Comment: @Casey For `SEQUENCE` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168311/generate-equidistant-sequence-of-number-in-one-cell-using-vba

Answer (score 2):

After help from @Mayukh Bhattacharya, I was able to accomplish my desired output by using his suggested macro for `SEQUENCE` **alone**.

```
Function SEQUENCE(min As Integer, max As Integer, steps As Integer) As String
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = min To max Step steps
    SEQUENCE = SEQUENCE & i & ","
  Next i
  SEQUENCE = Left(SEQUENCE, Len(SEQUENCE) - 1)
End Function
```

Written as `=SEQUENCE(1987,1990,1)` gave me `1987,1988,1989,1990`

Comment: Wow! Good One. Thank You for the share!